# import pymongo to pycharm

Tags: python, mongodb

hey i have a problem to import pymongo to pycharm even though i pip install pymongo library (the pycharm signed the first line as a problem), hope u could help me:)

my code:

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://heseim:xhxnvkvhxghocjhruo123@cluster0.jojs8.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")

db = client["test"]
collection = db["test"]

post = {"_id": 0, "name": "shaq", "score": 10}

collection.insert_one(post)
```

Comment: Chances are that the python interpreter you are using in pycharm is not that one you pip installed pymongo.

Answer (score 1):

In pycharm, go to File/Settings/Plugins and add the requirements plugin.

Then create a requirements.txt file in your project root and add in the single entry

```
 pymongo
```

Click back to your code and this banner should appear.

[image: pycharm requiremnents]

Click "Install requirement" to install pymongo.